# How to add attachments to AppointmentItem after attendees are added?

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments, outlook-2003

So I'm working away on a bit of code that takes an appointment and creates a few tasks from the appointment and checks to see if there is an attachement before it is sent off.

The code works fine when I have no other attendees. But as soon as the attendees are added, the code gets stuck on opening the file attachment dialogue box. Bleh!!

I've attached the code below:

```
Public WithEvents myItem As Outlook.appointmentitem

Private Sub myItem_Write(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim myResult As Integer
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olTsk As TaskItem
    Dim olAppt As appointmentitem
    Dim TskSubj As String
    Dim ApptSubj As String
    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myolApp As Outlook.Application

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olTsk = olApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)

    With olTsk
        olTsk.DueDate = myItem.Start - 1
        olTsk.Subject = myItem.Subject
        olTsk.Subject = replace(olTsk.Subject, "BC Test/Review", "Send BCP Docs")
        olTsk.Body = "Attending: " & myItem.RequiredAttendees
        olTsk.ReminderSet = True
        olTsk.ReminderTime = olTsk.DueDate & " " & Format("10:00 AM")

        End With

        olTsk.Save

    Set olTsk = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olTsk = olApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)

        With olTsk
        olTsk.DueDate = myItem.Start + 30
        olTsk.Subject = myItem.Subject
        olTsk.Body = "Attending: " & myItem.RequiredAttendees
        olTsk.ReminderSet = True
        olTsk.ReminderTime = olTsk.DueDate & " " & Format("10:00 AM")

                olTsk.Subject = replace(olTsk.Subject, "BC Test/Review", "BCP Updates due")

        End With

        olTsk.Save

    Set olTsk = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olTsk = olApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)

        With olTsk
        olTsk.DueDate = myItem.Start + 20
        olTsk.Subject = myItem.Subject
        olTsk.Body = "Attending: " & myItem.RequiredAttendees
        olTsk.ReminderSet = True
        olTsk.ReminderTime = olTsk.DueDate & " " & Format("10:00 AM")

                olTsk.Subject = replace(olTsk.Subject, "BC Test/Review", "BIA Team Leader Signature")

        End With

        olTsk.Save

    Set olTsk = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olTsk = olApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)

        With olTsk
        olTsk.DueDate = myItem.Start + 30
        olTsk.Subject = myItem.Subject
        olTsk.Body = "Attending: " & myItem.RequiredAttendees
        olTsk.ReminderSet = True
        olTsk.ReminderTime = olTsk.DueDate & " " & Format("10:00 AM")

                olTsk.Subject = replace(olTsk.Subject, "BC Test/Review", "BIA Executive Approver Signature")

        End With

        olTsk.Save

    Set olTsk = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olTsk = olApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)

        With olTsk
        olTsk.DueDate = myItem.Start + 1
        olTsk.Subject = myItem.Subject
        olTsk.Body = "Attending: " & myItem.RequiredAttendees
        olTsk.ReminderSet = True
        olTsk.ReminderTime = olTsk.DueDate & " " & Format("10:00 AM")

                olTsk.Subject = replace(olTsk.Subject, "BC Test/Review", "Send BIA Link")

        End With

        olTsk.Save

    Set olTsk = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

        Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olTsk = olApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)

        With olTsk
        olTsk.DueDate = myItem.Start + 30
        olTsk.Subject = myItem.Subject
        olTsk.Body = "Attending: " & myItem.RequiredAttendees
        olTsk.ReminderSet = True
        olTsk.ReminderTime = olTsk.DueDate & " " & Format("10:00 AM")

                olTsk.Subject = replace(olTsk.Subject, "BC Test/Review", "LDRPS")

        End With

        olTsk.Save

    Set olTsk = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

            MSG1 = MsgBox("Are BCP and BIA attached?", vbYesNo, "Yadda?")

            If MSG1 = vbYes Then
                myItem.Send
            Else
                MsgBox "Dude!  What are you thinking??"

                Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector
                Set myolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                Set myInspector = myItem.GetInspector
                Application.ActiveInspector.CommandBars.findcontrol(ID:=1079).Execute

                Exit Sub
                End If

End Sub
```

The code sticks on :

```
Application.ActiveInspector.CommandBars.findcontrol(ID:=1079).Execute
```

Any help would be much appriciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not post your entire code if you only need help debugging one line. And it's none of my business, but your code looks like it needs major refactoring. For starters, if this is Outlook VBA then why are you using the `New` keyword? No less than six times even.

Answer (score 0):

**Update/Edit:**

Since the "Insert File" button is grayed out when you are on the "Scheduling" page of the AppointmentItem form, switch to the "Appointment" page before running your code.

As an alternative, you may be able to switch to the "Appointment" page programmatically. Using the code in my original answer (see below), call the [SetCurrentFormPage Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa210290%28v=office.11%29.aspx) before attempting to click the "Insert File" button:

`apptInspector.SetCurrentFormPage("Appointment")`

**Original Answer:**

This is the relevant code block:

```
MsgBox "Dude!  What are you thinking??"                  
Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector                 
Set myolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")                 
Set myInspector = myItem.GetInspector               
Application.ActiveInspector.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=1079).Execute
```

You create an Inspector object and assign to it the AppointmentItem inspector, but instead of using that object's CommandBars.[FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa171234%28v=office.11%29.aspx) method, you use the one from `ActiveInspector` instead.

Since you have a reference to the Inspector for the appointment you are creating, try changing

`Application.ActiveInspector.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=1079).Execute`

to

`myInspector.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=1079).Execute`

and see if that works.

Comment: No luck there.  Bummer.  I just have no idea why adding a recipient would cause it to missfire on this.  I've put in a debug.print thing, and know that the inspector still has hold of the appointment.

Comment: AH HAH!!!!  So, it seems that the code works with a recipient IF I am on the original appointment page.  But If i click my little button on the add recipient page, it won't work.  I suspect that it is because the UI changes, and the add recipient page is actually a new UI and thereby not selected by the inspector!  YAY ME!